# System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'ChatBotDashboard.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate Controller

Tags: c#, api, controller, whatsapp, dbcontext

Error: System invalid operation exception: unable to resolve service for type Chat Bot Dashboard Application Db Context while attempting to activate Chatbot API Test Controller

I am coding a WHATSAPP Chat Bot using ASP Net Core C# on Visual Studio. I have two projects in the solution. I am getting the error message on Postman when I run the project and send this basic Post Request to the API.

From what I understand, the Web App Db Context isn't able to resolve a service type while activating the API Controller in the second Project.
NB: Dependency Injection is used in this API Controller.

How do I overcome this Error on Postman?

[Postman API Request Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqNzF.jpg)[Test Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHE5H.jpg)[Startup Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljS1v.jpg)[Program File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeCvo.jpg)[Program File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYvpk.jpg)

Comment: I guess you have a constructor injection and you are injecting any type which you have not registered in your IoC container.

Comment: Yes I have attempted dependency injection. What configurations do I still require?

Comment: I tend to say that you have not registered ChatBotDashboard.ApplicationDbContext in the container.

Comment: What type of project is the second one? Depending on the type, it might be necessary to register the `ApplicationDbContext ` there as well, e.g. if it is it's own independent web API project.

Comment: @Sebastian S. Yes I may have some configurations which are wrong in my container.

Comment: @user7217806 Its a ASP.Net Web Core App and a ASP.Net Core project

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Register the database context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#register-the-database-context) (ensure to view it for the ASP.NET Core version that you use!) for a guide of how to register the database context for the second ASP.NET Core project as well.

Comment: builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))); I have the above line in my Program.cs file which targets the DbContext. @user7217806

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both projects probably are individually runnable, and therefore have their own [dependency injection container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection). So they both register the services (e.g. like `services.Add...`) they need to use in their own `Program.cs` or `Startup.cs` files, which then only are accessible in the corresponding project, instead of both projects.

This is why you would need to [register the database context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#register-the-database-context) (ensure to view it for the ASP.NET Core version that you use) in the second ASP.NET Core project as well.